# phpMyAdmin Database Updates using sql file

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have two machines each with phpmyadmin installed which have a mirror setup - same databases, same tables...and so on.

I updated one of these instances with a new column in a few tables in various databases. I now want to update the other instance to match but when I import the sql.zip file (that I exported from the first machine) I get an error saying that the table (first table) already exists. I know this! I just want to update it.

I thought that when you imported data it checks for the existence of said tables/databases first and then creates them if needed?

What am I doing wrong please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you export your sql.zip file in phpMyAdmin, check the "IF NOT EXISTS" option in the export dialog. That will make the create table statements optional and not error out if the tables already exist.

Comment: Thank you, that overcame that issue.

Comment: Could I be cheeky and ask another question?? The original database has had an additional column added to an existing table - when importing the databases to the (copy) second phpmyadmin instance it errors. Is there an option/statement for this? I've looked through and tried a couple of them but no joy. Thanks.

Comment: Unlikely, but you could temporarily add that column and remove it again after the import.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open your sql file on text editor
2. If you found sytax to make a table just delete it
   the code looks like this

   CREATE TABLE `table_name` (
   `name` int(11) ...
   ...
   ...
   )
   delete that code on your sql file
3. Find syntax INSERT INTO then replace with REPLACE INTO
   ex.
   INSERT INTO `tb_name` (id,name) VALUES (1,2)
   became
   REPLACE INTO `tb_name` (id,name) VALUES (1,2)
4. Then enjoy your SQL Update on other machine

I think my comment is 3 years late and I think the owner of the post already knows the solution. but at least useful for those who just visited here